# Firebase Function returned before data is fetched completely

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Firebase function return ob2 before data is fetched from firestore via loop

```
return admin.firestore().collection("doctors").doc(data.type).listCollections().then(function (doc) {

    // console.log(doc);
    var arr=[];
    let ob2;
    for(let coll of doc) {
        ob2=admin.firestore().collection("doctors").doc(data.type).collection(coll.id).doc("docdetail").get().
        then((x)=>{
                    arr.push(x.data());
                    obj.users=arr;
                    return obj;
        })

    }
  console.log(ob2);
  return ob2;
})
```

Comment: Please edit the question to show the entire code of the Cloud Function that isn't working the way you expect.  Also indicate what the function should generate.  Is it going to send a response to the client?  Or something else?

Answer (score 1):

Your issue here is you aren't using promises properly. your code at the bottom "return ob2" is executed immediately before anything is returned.  Modify your code to the below code and it should hopefully work.  Or better yet use async await.

```
return admin.firestore().collection("doctors").doc(data.type).listCollections().then(function (doc) {

// console.log(doc);
var arr=[];
let ob2;
for(let coll of doc) {
    return admin.firestore().collection("doctors").doc(data.type).collection(coll.id).doc("docdetail").get().
    then((x)=>{
                arr.push(x.data());
                obj.users=arr;
                console.log(obj);
                return obj;
    })

   };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're working with a [document reference](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/DocumentReference.html).

An example is [posted online](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/DocumentReference.html):

```
let documentRef = firestore.doc('col/doc');

documentRef.listCollections().then(collections => {
  for (let collection of collections) {
    console.log(`Found subcollection with id: ${collection.id}`);
  }
});
```